# Can't disable Sandbox mode in Facebook application settings

Tags: facebook

I created a Facebook app in http://www.facebook.com/developers/ to get an Application ID, following the instructions given [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android).
I tried to disable Sandbox mode, which seems to only authorize the developper to login to the app, but I get

```
Validation failed.
Tried to switch out of sandboxed mode while still using an FBML Canvas. Need to switch to an IFrame Canvas before disabling sandbox mode.
```

What's wrong? I only set the name of the app and the android hashkey. Do I have to set something else (like Facebook Integration settings)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a bug on the creation page of a facebook application.

Answer (score 2):

Note that only admins of an app are able to enable/disable sandbox mode. Developers and others will find that setting grayed out.

Jeremy

Answer (score 1):

Try switching the app into sandbox mode then save it. Disable deprecated FBML and sandbox mode and then save it again.

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to "fix" this issue by adding another FB Administrator for the app then going to that account and Reseting it out of sandbox mode. Hope this helps others.